# Find a value between two of the same characters in a string using Python

Tags: python, strings

I am attempting to make a python script that imports a given file.

Then on the import of the file, I am pulling a value from in the filename to determine what function to run.

I will then eventually extend this to pull all files from a folder rather than explicitly pass it a specific file.

The format of the file names is always the following:

```
blah_Value_blah.extension
```

I am wondering if there is a better and more efficient way to pull **Value** from the above example than what I have given below?

Here is my code:

```
from os.path import splitext, basename

under = '_'

base = basename(splitext(filename_goes_here)[0])
value = base[base.find(under)+len(under):base.rfind(under)]
```

I am aware I can merge my two lines of code above into one line but it would be very unsightly.

Examples of the filenames are:

```
//path/to/file/GAME_team_2017.csv
//path/to/file/GAME_player_2017.csv
//path/to/file/GAME_rules_2017.csv
```

The sample output of the above files would be:

```
'team'
'player'
'rules'
```

Comment: Why not make this a function? With good defaults, and an example usage. It'd make the question smaller to read, and not look like example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `str.find`, you could better describe yourself using regex. However it's not that much of an improvement.

For example using the regex `_(.+)_` on the `basename` of the file is all you need. If you think a file extension is going to have an `_` then you may need the `splitext`.

This can get:

```
from os.path import splitext, basename
from re import search

base = basename(splitext(filename_goes_here)[0])
value = search('_(.+)_', base)
if value is not None:
    value = value.group(1)
```

If you're [using Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.__getitem__), as noted in the comments by [200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success), you could change the last line to:

```
value = value[0]
```

Comment: Why not simplify the last line to `value = value.group(1)`?

Comment: In Python 3.6, you could also write [`value = value[1]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.__getitem__).

Answer (score 0):

Since you said the format of the file names is always `blah_Value_blah.extension`, I would simply split the name at `_` and access the value at `index 1`. For example, `'GAME_player_2017.csv'.split('_')[1]`

If you have a list like this

```
filenames = ['GAME_team_2017.csv',
             'GAME_player_2017.csv',
             'GAME_rules_2017.csv']
```

I would split each string and get item at `index 1` with a `list comprehension`.

```
values = [name.split('_')[1] for name in filenames]
```

To make the code reusable, I would turn it into a function using `listdir()` from `os` module:

```
from os import listdir

def get_values(path_to_folder):
    filenames = listdir(path_to_folder)
    values = [name.split('_')[1] for name in filenames]
    return values
```

Now you could call the function with a path as an argument and based on the returned values you could determine what function to run.

For example:

```
values = get_values(path_to_folder)

for value in values:
    # determine what function to run
```

Answer (score -1):

can adapt from here, just adjust your regex

```
import os
import re


def key(filename):
   # extract category from filename
    pattern = '(\s|\_)\d{4}.*'  # space/underscore & 4 digit date &  the rest
    return re.sub(pattern, '', os.path.basename(filename))
```